# Error Attempt to De-Reference A Null Object For a Results Member Variable

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

I have a Dynamic Apex class and having a problem in the Results class with the outputMember assignment. I should be returning a List to Flow with this. I have confirmed that the Sobject is not null and assuming I have not initialized my List correctly but not clear how.

`ERROR: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

```
public with sharing class AddressBulkifyClass {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Collect Bulkified Records' category='Bulkify Records')
  public static List<Results> execute(List<Request> requestList) {

 code...
    List<SObject> outputList = Database.query(
      'SELECT ' +
      queryFields +
      ' FROM ' +
      sObjectType +
      ' WHERE Id IN :idSet'
    );

    List<Results> responseWrapper = new List<Results>();
    Results results = new Results();

    for (SObject curSobject : outputList) {
      System.debug('Sobject ' + curSobject);
      if (curSobject != null) {
        **results.outputMember.add(curSobject);**
        responseWrapper.add(results);
      }
    }
    //    results.outputMember.add(curSobject);

    System.debug('Return responseWrapper size ' + responseWrapper.size());
    return responseWrapper;
  }

  public with sharing class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Record ID' required=true)
    public Id recordId;
    public List<SObject> requestList;
    @InvocableVariable(label='Field List' required=true)
    public List<String> fieldList;
  }

  public with sharing class Results {
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='Records for output'
      description='Sobject collection from recordIds input'
      required=true
    )
    public List<SObject> outputMember;
  }
}
```

Comment: N.B. `curSobject` will never be null because `outputList` is a collection of 0..n members and if empty, the for loop executes 0 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but it looks like your error is in line `results.outputMember.add(curSobject);`.

If that is the case, then the solution is simple. Since you never initialized the list `outputMember` inside the variable `results`, you cannot add any objects to it. You have two ways to fix this.

**Option one**

Add `results.outputMember = new List<SObject>()` directly above the line that is currently failing

**Option two** (I'd prefer it)

Inside your `Results` class, create a constructor and initialize your variable there

Your inner class would look like this

```
public with sharing class Results {
    @InvocableVariable(
      label='Records for output'
      description='Sobject collection from recordIds input'
      required=true
    )
    public List<SObject> outputMember;

   public Results() {
     this.outputMember = new List<SObject>():
   }
  }
```

**PostScript**:

I want to point out that if you're going to add the `results` object to a collection, you will want to initialize it **inside** the loop, not outside

Comment: Tried every permutation of Option 1 except the right answer! Why is Option 2 preferred? For Readability or performance?

Comment: Neither, really, I prefer it because it removes the need for the person implementing the class to remember to initialize the collection and avoids issues like the one you encountered today